# Unwanted white space between picture drawn by tikz and page border

Tags: tikz-pgf

I draw a sloped band at the corner of page, but unwanted white space appears between the pic and page boder. I guess that is caused by node text. But why? And is there a better way to eliminate the space？
MWE：

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,picture,eso-pic,calc}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\drawband[3]{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
      \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \tikz\draw[fill=gray,draw=red,above,line width=#3]
        (0,#1)-- node[midway,sloped]{node text}
        (#1,0)--
        (#1+#2,0)--
        (0,#1+#2)--cycle;%
      }}}

\drawband{1cm}{1cm}{1pt}
first page\clearpage second page
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use overlay here. (This makes the specification `\AtPageLowerLeft{` unnecessary but it does not hurt.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,picture,eso-pic,calc}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\drawband[3]{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
      \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[fill=gray,draw=red,above,line width=#3]
        ([yshift=#1]current page.south west)-- node[midway,sloped]{node text}
        ([xshift=#1]current page.south west)--
        ([xshift=#1+#2]current page.south west)--
        ([yshift=#1+#2]current page.south west)--cycle;}%
      }}}

\drawband{1cm}{1cm}{1pt}
first page\clearpage second page
\end{document}
```

[image]

This code is shorter and does the same:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,eso-pic}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\drawband[3]{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
        \tikzlay,remember picture]{\draw[overlay,fill=gray,draw=red,above,line width=#3]
        ([yshift=#1]current page.south west)-- node[midway,sloped]{node text}
        ([xshift=#1]current page.south west)--
        ([xshift=#1+#2]current page.south west)--
        ([yshift=#1+#2]current page.south west)--cycle;}%
}}

\drawband{1cm}{1cm}{1pt}
first page\clearpage second page
\end{document}
```

See section **17.13.2 Referencing the Current Page Node – Absolute Positioning** of the pgfmanual for details how this works.

I personally would perhaps change the command to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,eso-pic}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{band/.style={}}
\newcommand\drawband[3][line width=1pt]{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
        \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\draw[fill=gray,draw=red,above,#1]
        ([yshift=#2]current page.south west)--
        ([xshift=#2]current page.south west)--
        ([xshift=#2+#3]current page.south west)--
        ([yshift=#2+#3]current page.south west)--cycle;
        \path ([yshift=#2+#3/2]current page.south west) -- 
        node[midway,sloped]{node text}
         ([xshift=#2+#3/2]current page.south west);}%
}}

\drawband{1cm}{1cm}
first page\clearpage second page
\end{document}
```

[image]

so that you have full flexibility to change the style whenever you feel like it, and which centers the text in the band. **EDIT**: Added `remember picture` to the examples, big thanks to @lyl!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help which gives me another valuable method of constructing waterprint and also new review for tikz!!

Comment: @lyl You're welcome! (I added a suggestion for a slightly different syntax, but I do not have the full picture, so it may not be a useful suggestion.)

Comment: In tikz, is there a method by which the \AddToShipoutPictureBG can also be canceled?

Comment: @lyl What do you mean by "canceled"? If you mean "not use this command", the answer is that in principle you only need `atbegshi`, which `eso-pic` is using. But you need AFAIK something that hooks in every page (like `atbegshi`).

Comment: I mean use purely tizk instead of eso-pic to construct waterprint in every page, thus the \AddToShipoutPictureBG is not necessary. And AFAIK is ?

Comment: @lyl I am not absolutely sure but to the best of my knowledge you need something that tells TeX to do that on every page, and before "shipping out the page" if you want it on the background. This is what `atbegshi` does, and `eso-pic` makes use of it.

Comment: why "remember picture" is not necessary in this example?

Comment: @lyl That's actually a good point. Frankly, I do not know, and it might be safer to add `remember picture`. At least all the examples in the manual do it.

Comment: @lyl I added a simple way to center the text in the band.

Comment: Thanks again especially for addding a simple way to center the text in the band!! Is there a universal way to find the center position of any  closed picture?

Comment: @lyl Yes and no. It depends on how you define center. For instance, in section **13.2.2 Barycentric Systems** of the pgfmanual you find the `barycentric cs:` which yield the barycenters. Or there is the `path picture` node, which also has a center, which in general does not coincide with the barycenter. And there is the `local bounding box` which also has a center.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the text is slightly too wide for the picture, set it into a zero width box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,picture,eso-pic,calc}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\drawband[3]{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
      \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \tikz\draw[fill=gray,draw=red,above,line width=#3]
        (0,#1)-- node[midway,sloped]{\makebox[0pt]{node text}}
        (#1,0)--
        (#1+#2,0)--
        (0,#1+#2)--cycle;%
      }}}

\drawband{1cm}{1cm}{1pt}

\mbox{} % force a page to be produced

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's how you can place the text in the middle of the trapezoid:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,picture,eso-pic,calc}

\newcommand\drawband[3]{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[fill=gray,draw=red,above,line width=#3]
        (0,#1)--(#1,0)--(#1+#2,0)--(0,#1+#2)--cycle;
      \node at ({(#1*2+#2)/4},{(#1*2+#2)/4})[rotate=-45,inner sep=-#1]
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\drawband{1cm}{1cm}{1pt}

\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to disregard ascenders and descenders, smash the text and insert a phantom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,picture,eso-pic,calc}

\newcommand\drawband[3]{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[fill=gray,draw=red,above,line width=#3]
        (0,#1)--(#1,0)--(#1+#2,0)--(0,#1+#2)--cycle;
      \node at ({(#1*2+#2)/4},{(#1*2+#2)/4})[rotate=-45,inner sep=-#1]
        {\smash{node text}\vphantom{x}};
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\drawband{1cm}{1cm}{1pt}

\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: a simple but excellent solution! Thank you @egreg. And how to put the node text in middle position of vertical direction? You see, it's boring to try the option `above=...` many times to get a good positon in vertical dirction.

Comment: @lyl I think it's better to set the text in a node by itself. Added some code.

Comment: When #1=#2, we can conclude (#1*3/4,#1*3/4). When #1 is not equal #2, the new factor has to be re-compute. So, is there a universal way to put node just at center of a closed pic like trapezoid in this example?

Comment: @lyl I did the geometry for you.